# Having in SQL statement isn't returning accurate results

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, having

I have a query that returns customer data from a temp table. The temp table only stores a customer number first and last names. It has about 320 records for folks who qualified for a program.

```
create table #customers
(
customer_no int,
fname varchar(20),
lname varchar(55)
)
```

What I need to do from the database is say give me everyone from our entire database who has the combination of first name and last name (to find the duplicates).  We also need to pull addresses, but we don't want to use customer number in our search because we need it for later but for now we want the comparison to be strictly on the first and last names.

```
select  distinct a.customer_no,
        a.fname,
        a.mname,
        a.lname,
        b.street1,
        b.street2,
        b.city,
        b.state,
        b.postal_code
from    T_CUSTOMER a
join    T_ADDRESS b on a.customer_no = b.customer_no
where   (
        lname in (select lname from #customers) and 
        fname in (select fname from #customers)
        )
order by a.lname, a.fname
```

so the query comes back with a nice long list of records - however because there is a lot of duplicates combinations (it brings back the customer number multiple times).

for example:

```
customer_no fname   mname   lname   street1             city
86224371    John    NULL    Cornid  11 Maplewood Dr.    New Haven
86224371    John    NULL    Cornid  11 Maplewood Drive  Hartford
86313525    John    NULL    Cornid  11 Maplewood Dr     Hartford
86390546    John    Seth    Cornid  11 Maplewood dr.    New Haven
```

So the data is correct. 
The only issue is I want to suppress the first line - I want to say give me unique customer numbers only. I want my output to be:

```
    customer_no fname   mname   lname   street1             city
    86224371    John    NULL    Cornid  11 Maplewood Dr.    New Haven
    86313525    John    NULL    Cornid  11 Maplewood Dr     Hartford
    86390546    John    Seth    Cornid  11 Maplewood dr.    New Haven
```

We have to provide basic information to clean the data -- We only want each customer number pulled once.

```
select  distinct a.customer_no,
        a.fname,
        a.mname,
        a.lname,
        b.street1,
        b.street2,
        b.city,
        b.state,
        b.postal_code
from    T_CUSTOMER a
join    T_ADDRESS b on a.customer_no = b.customer_no
where   (
        lname in (select lname from #customers) and 
        fname in (select fname from #customers)
        )
group by    a.customer_no,
            a.fname,
            a.mname,
            a.lname,
            b.street1,
            b.street2,
            b.city,
            b.state,
            b.postal_code
having count(a.customer_no) > 1
order by a.lname, a.fname
```

i wrote the above to include having count customer_no > 1 but it doesn't work because it returns an empty data set.

please advise. 
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a join

```
select
        a.customer_no,
        a.fname,
        a.mname,
        a.lname,
        b.street1,
        b.street2,
        b.city,
        b.state,
        b.postal_code
from T_CUSTOMER a
join T_ADDRESS b on a.customer_no = b.customer_no
join #customers c on a.lname = c.lname and a.fname = c.fname
order by a.lname, a.fname
```

as a side note, if you have to use distinct you are probably doing it wrong.

---

sometimes you need to do this:

```
join #customers c on upper(a.lname) = upper(c.lname) and upper(a.fname) = upper(c.fname)
```

sometimes you need to do this:

```
join #customers c on trim(a.lname) = trim(c.lname) and trim(a.fname) = trim(c.fname)
```

---

It might be a different question but in the comment below

> We have a record with multiple addresses and its being returned and
>   counted multiple times. But i only want that to happen if the names
>   are different - and customer numbers are different

To only "count" once I would do this:

```
select * from
(
  select a.customer_no,
        a.fname,
        a.mname,
        a.lname,
        b.street1,
        b.street2,
        b.city,
        b.state,
        b.postal_code
        row_number(partition by a.fname, a.lname, a.customer_no
                   order by street1, stree2) as rn
  from    T_CUSTOMER a
  join    T_ADDRESS b on a.customer_no = b.customer_no
) x
where rn = 1
```

Not I would suggest a better field than street1 as the order by, like update date or create date.

Comment: Apologies for the changes here ... it's not working. I have the first set of records coming back twice. 86224371, 86224371, 86313525, 86390546. Yes the addresses are different but i don't care about those. I need to provide the user with unique customer numbers. so i need it to be 86224371, 86313525, 86390546 only.

Comment: ok, how is it not working... what were you expecting that it is not doing?

Comment: We have a record with multiple addresses and its being returned and counted multiple times. But i only want that to happen if the names are different - and customer numbers are different.

Comment: There is nothing in your question that involves counting so I have no idea what you mean by "being returned and counted"

Comment: if you take a look at my out put data the first one with the 4 lines, the customer number appears twice on two records - because with the join there are two addresses. what i want is that to come back once. i don't care which record but the customer number should come once (like i have in my third output set example)

Comment: @Elizabeth - ok there is a query there that will do that.

Comment: I have to run, but it looks good. I will test it tomorrow. Thank you for your help